# How to use knitr to compare performance of different versions of R?

Tags: r, knitr

I want to evaluate the performance of some code in different versions of R.  This is easy enough in principle:

- Start R
- Use `system.time()` to measure the time it takes to run a piece of code
- Terminate R
- Rinse and repeat in a different version

Now, I want to use `knitr` to create a report to do this.  So, it seems to me I need a mechanism to start a new session in each chunk.

How do I do this?

---

Some sample `knitr`  markdown code to serve as a demonstration. This code plots a graphic using `ggplot`, but clearly both versions return identical timings, since I don't know how to start a new version of R for each chunk.

````
Comparison of R performance
========================================================

# Do analysis in R version 2.14

```{r fig.width=6, fig.height=3}
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)

system.time({
  p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price/carat, colour=clarity)) + geom_point()
  print(p)
})
```


# Repeat same analysis in R 2.15

```{r fig.width=6, fig.height=3}
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)

system.time({
  p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price/carat, colour=clarity)) + geom_point()
  print(p)
})
```
````

Comment: Couldn't you just have a `bash` script or whatnot do all the starting/stopping of R sessions, have each session write out its results to a file, and then use `knitr` to read all the log files in and summarize the results?  Not as elegant, but maybe more accurate and easier.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman Yes, probably. But that sounds like work!

Comment: Reckon you need to use `system()` to run another R process...

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I'll add an `Rscript` [engine](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/engines/) in `knitr`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding the `Rscript` engine in `knitr` [was easy](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/a373964ce06a87cecd0008853bb097ed9c3290ac), but I was held back by [an R bug](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2013-March/066066.html). Anyway, this engine is available since [version 1.1.5](https://github.com/yihui/knitr) and will be on CRAN as version 1.2.

Now you can specify the chunk option `engine='Rscript'` and `engine.path='path/to/the/desired/Rscript'`.

For large scale performance comparisons, I think what Ari B. Friedman suggested in the comment above is a better way to go. It will be pretty tedious to type the engine paths if you have many code chunks for comparisons.